# Connecting USB Xbox Controller to National Instruments cRIO

Tags: control, industrial-robot, wireless, usb, first-robotics

I have a FIRST Robotics spec National Instruments cRIO.  I would like to connect a USB wireless Xbox controller to it in order to control it from a distance with minimal extra hardware (which is why I am not using the more traditional WiFi radio method).  To this point I have been able to find either

A. A sidecar for the cRIO which allows it to act as a USB host or

B. A method that does not use NI specific hardware to connect the two together

If someone who is knowledgeable on the subjects of industrial system and robot control could provide some assistance that would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can line the Xbox controller to the FIRST dashboard software as a joystick, this would be the easiest solution, If you want to attach it directly you could use the serial port on the Crio with a [USB host shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoUSBHostShield) and an arduino (similar to [this](http://scuola.arduino.cc/courses/lessons/cover/wXd2go1)) and configure the arduino to translate the data to serial and then read it. the second option is to connect the SPI lines on the shield directly to the GPIO on the digital sidecar and use the included SPI interface in the WPI library. Additional modules for the Crio will not be supported in the FIRST configuration, requiring to write your own libraries and FPGA implementation from the ground up to support more than just the offical modules, along with the fact that they are very expensive.

Comment: Thanks!  I've decided to go with an Arduino Uno and the USB host shield you mentioned.  This will do everything I need without even having to use the cRIO!